# PhpMyAdmin v5.1.3 Export Suddenly Stop Working Chrome Failed - Network Error

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Have anyone experienced an issue with phpmyadmin suddenly stop exporting? I am running MariaDB 10.3.28, nginx, Php 8.0.17 on Rocky Linux. I don't know if the recent update from Rocky Linux breaks something but I was using the export function 2-3 week ago.

I looked at the nginx error log and there was non being recorded. I enable debug in the log and I got:

writev() Failed 32 Broken pipe while sending to client...

I tried to disable firewalld, selinux and tweak nginx config that I can think off, nothing helped.

Anyone can give me a hint please, it will greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How big is the export and how long does it take? ... `broken pipe` typically implies timeout, but is obviously not the _only_ reason, of course.

Comment: @PaulT. I tried it in a very small table or with table with no data at all, I get the same error. It's actually not doing anything, I get the error right away.

Answer (score -1):

## Tl;dr

Today I had a problem very close to the one you are experiencing. I fixed it reverting to the previous version of phpmyadmin (5.1.1).

---

### What I did (I'm using docker):

Nginx error log:

```
*96 client canceled stream 1 while reading upstream, client: ...
```

I tried first editing nginx `proxy_buffering` alongside `proxy_request_buffering` without luck

Editing phpmyadmin `mime_type` variable inside `Export.php` class does not resolve the problem

At the end I looked up docker hub and found that a new version was pushed `11 hours ago` I then decided to revert to previous version and everything works as expected

Comment: I tried downgrading but it's the same error.

Comment: @FrogyDiak Have you tried using only the phpmyadmin container without the reverse proxy?